# parsed kubeconfig is invalid for incluster kube-rs usage

Tags: kubernetes, rust, digital-ocean, kubernetes-operator

I am trying to use kube-rs/kube from within a k8s deployment as:

```
    let client = Client::try_default().await?;
```

but get errors as it tries to process a JWT token as a kubeconfig file:

```
   kubeconfig: (the structure of the parsed kubeconfig is invalid: invalid type: string "XXX"
```

where XXX is a b64 token.

I can't find any docs explaining how to instantiate the client differently incluster vs standalone (standalone works as it finds `~/.kube/config` on my dev machine).

The k8s cluster is managed k8s at Digital Ocean.

My chart creates a service account which is named in the decoded token the kube-rs call to instantiate the client is choking on as it tries to process the token as a `kubeconfig` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was not related to kube-rs usage.  My service account was improperly specified in my chart and a `KUBECONFIG` env var was erroneously defined telling my app to think the token file was a `kubeconfig`.

Removing the `KUBECONFIG` env var and removing the explicit volume mounts for the service account solved this issue and the code is now smart enough to recognize when it is in `incluster` context.